# apply a snakemake rule on a list of values in parallel

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm currently exploring using snakemake as a workflow tool.

In my specific use case I don't start from a list of files but rather from a list of values that should result in the creation of a list of files.

In my example, I create the files with a small python snippet which works fine but when I want to use those files in parallel in a second rule, they are concatenated into one parameter:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{file}.bar', file=data)

rule foo:
    output:
        expand('{file}.foo', file=data)
    run:
        for item in data:
            with open(f'{item}.foo', 'w') as fout:
                fout.write('foo')

rule bar:
    input:
        file=expand('{file}.foo', file=data)
    output:
        outfile=expand('{file}.bar', file=data)
    shell:
        """echo {output.outfile};echo bar > {output.outfile} """
```

the example prints

"one.bar two.bar three.bar"

at once, so the rule is applied only once,

and then raises an error because the expected output files are not created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want rule `bar` without `expand`'s:

```
rule bar:
    input:
        file='{file}.foo',
    output:
        outfile='{file}.bar',
    shell:
        """echo {output.outfile};echo bar > {output.outfile} """
```

this is because you apply this rule to each `{file}` individually not to all of them at once. You would use `expand` if, for example, you wanted to concatenate all `{file}`'s in a single one.

By the same reasoning, you could also change rule `foo` to:

```
rule foo:
    output:
        '{file}.foo',
    run:
        item=wildcards.file
        with open(f'{item}.foo', 'w') as fout:
            fout.write('foo')
```

(not tested)

Comment: Indeed, thanks.
I mixed up the concepts it seems. expand is normal behavior to concatenate, so you end up with one value

Answer (score 2):

The last rule should be changed to remove `expand` (since this rule is creating only a single file):

```py
rule bar:
    input:
        file=expand('{file}.foo', file=data)
    output:
        outfile='{file}.bar'
    shell:
        """echo {output.outfile}; echo bar > {output.outfile} """
```